# How to rewrite URL in sails.js

Tags: sails.js

Anyone can help me,i want to rewrite url from http://www.example.in/search?city='xyz'
to
http://www.example.in/city/xyz
in sails.js

Comment: Is there something you tried that didn't work?  Have you looked at any Sails documentation, for example the [controllers docs](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/controllers#?what-does-a-controller-file-look-like) that show an example of redirecting a URL?

Answer (score 0):

Check the [url slug](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/routes/url-slugs) section of the documentation.

You could create a route like this one:

```js
// config/routes.js
module.exports.routes = {
  // The simple route you use to access to the search controller for now
  'get /search': 'SearchController.index'

  // The "rewritten" route that calls the same controller
  // processing ":city" as if it was part of the query string
  'get /city/:city': 'SearchController.index'
}
```

Then, `http://www.example.in/search?city=xyz` and `http://www.example.in/city/xyz` will have the same result, like if you had used url rewriting with Nginx or Apache.